# Remove old hardened caulk

Tags: bathroom, caulking

I'm planning to re-caulk my bathtub as the existing caulk is deteriorating. My house was built in 2005 but am not sure if the bathtub is original to the house. Unlike the flexible silicone caulk commonly mentioned in Youtube tutorials, the caulk in my bathroom is quite hard and doesn't scrape off easily. Could anyone provide insights into what this type of hard caulk is and the best methods for removal? Also, I've heard about leaving the "weep hole" at the lowest point of the bathtub unsealed. Is this a recommended practice?

[image: Cracked caulk]

[image: Hard caulk around the "weep hole"]

Comment: Hard to tell from pictures, but it could be regular hard caulk or siliconized grout from a tube. Since you’re up against plastic, I suggest you try plastic razor blades first. That surface is easy to scratch with a razor blade or knife.

Comment: +1 on razor blades, but you gotta be careful since that looks like a composite surround.  If you can, pull off the spout first.